# Python3: Subclass of Process, call methods in run()

Tags: python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing, command-pattern

I've tried to extend the `multiprocessing.Process` class to use it in a Command pattern way... There is a scheduler instance, where the client invokes commands and calls for execution. But the command code never terminates after `self.execute()` is called. Here is the command class:

```
   class Command(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.result = None
        self.command_name = type(self).__name__
        self.shell = False      

    #from Process
    def run(self):
        super().run()
        print("running "+self.command_name)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        self.execute()
        print("finished "+self.command_name)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.exit(0)

    def execute(self):
        pass
```

the idea is simple that each sub class  of Command provides its own code in the execute() method. For instances:

```
class LoadCommand(Command):
 def __init__(self,parameterA,...):
     super().__init__()
     ...

 def execute(self):
     print("executing LoadCommand")
     ....
     return
```

this is my scheduler:

```
class Scheduler:
_instance = None
_history_queue = []
_command_queue = []
_logger = None
#IPC, negative maxsize means infinite size
_pipe = Queue(maxsize=-1)

def __init__(self):
    raise RuntimeError('Call getInstance() instead')

@classmethod
def getInstance(cls):
    if cls._instance is None:
        cls._instance = cls.__new__(cls)
    return cls._instance

def getPipe(self):
    print(self._pipe)
    return self._pipe

def enqueueCommand(self,command):
    # if isinstance(command,Command):
        self._command_queue.append(command)

def executeQueue(self, synchronicMode):
    while len(self._command_queue) > 0:
        command = self._command_queue.pop(0)    
        command.start()
        if synchronicMode:
            #wait until this process is done
            print("Waiting\n")              
            command.join(10)
            if command.is_alive():
                print("process isn't finished")
            else:
                print("process finished")               
        self._history_queue.append(command)
```

I've tried to call sys.exit(0) immediately after the run begins with success (process terminates). So maybe there is an error in the inheritance hierarchy, but I can't see it.